# Active Record: Query different associations that belong to the same parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a Rails application where users may select the shows they are watching, and which episodes they have already watched. The ActiveRecord associations look somewhat like this:

```
class User
  has_many :episodes_joins, :dependent => :delete_all, class_name: 'UsersEpisodesJoin'
  has_many :episodes, through: :episodes_joins
  has_many :shows_joins, :dependent => :delete_all, class_name: 'UsersShowsJoin'
  has_many :shows, through: :shows_joins
end

class Show
  has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users_shows_joins, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :users, through: :users_shows_joins
end

class Episode
  belongs_to :show
  has_many :users_episodes_joins, :dependent => :delete_all
  has_many :users, through: :users_episodes_joins
end

class UsersShowsJoin
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :show
end

class UsersEpisodesJoin
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :episode
end
```

I wish to allow users to filter "special episodes" for each show individually ("special episodes" have episode.special? set to true). For this, I was thinking of adding a boolean column in the UsersShowsJoins table named `filter_specials`. I now wish to do something like this:

```
episodes = user.episodes.where(special: false).to_a
user.episodes.where(special: true) do |epi|
  show_join = UsersShowsJoins.where(user_id: user.id, show_id: epi.show.id).first
  episodes << epi if show_join.nil? || !show_join.filter_specials?
end
# do something with 'episodes',
# which contains all non-special episodes,
# as well as special episodes of shows for which the user is not filtering these
```

I know this is a very hackish and slow implementation that will do tons of DB queries, and I'm sure there's a much better way to do it, possibly even with a single query.

Additionally, I want to be able to query the DB for all shows a user has selected, and pre-load the corresponding episodes that have a UsersEpisodesJoins row for the same user. Something like:

```
shows = user.shows.all
h = {}
shows.each do |show|
  episodes = user.episodes.where(show_id: show.id).all
  h[show] = episodes
end

# do something with h,
# which contains a user's watched episodes for each selected show
```

How can I write these queries efficiently, so that I don't incur N+1 problems for complex queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to write the special episodes filter like this:

```
show_joins = UsersShowsJoins.joins(:shows, :users).where(episodes: { special: true})
```

This will join both `shows` and `users` by their common relationship, and filter for the episodes that have `special` set to `true`.

There are variations that you could write, based on what type of object you wanted to work with as the main object:

```
shows = Show.joins(:users, :episodes).where(episodes: {special: true})
```

or:

```
episodes = Episode.joins(shows: :users).where(special: true)
```

For the second query, you can use this:

```
user.shows.includes(:episodes).all
```

That should pre-load the episodes for the shows that the user is watching.  You could add `where` conditions, `group`-ing, and even `order` conditions if you choose, like so:

```
user.shows.includes(:episodes).order("shows.title")
```

to order the results by the show title (assuming that there is a show title field).

The [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) guide has some great examples in the [Joining Tables](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables) section.  It's worth reading through to get some ideas about how to efficiently do complex querying like this.

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed, I had read through the AR guide, but didn't notice they had such a detailed Joining Tables section, so thanks for pointing it out.